# How many ways are there to pack $9$ identical DVDs into $3$ indistinguishable boxes?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> How many ways are there to pack $9$ identical DVDs into $3$ indistinguishable boxes so that each box contains at least two DVDs?

---

Is this having one to one correspondence with the partitions of a number?

Comment: Put two DVD's in each box. You still have $3*3=9$ ways of placing the remaining 3 DVD's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's the number of partitions of $3$ with at most $3$ parts, but since $3\leq3$ the extra condition doesn't add anything in this case.

(The first $3$ is the number of DVDs you have left after putting the minimum number into each box, and the second is the number of boxes.)

So there are $3$ ways, which correspond to the partitions $3$, $2+1$, $1+1+1$, and have boxes with $5,2,2$ or $4,3,2$ or $3,3,3$ DVDs respectively.

Comment: Thanks, This is what I wanted !!